# Query on test automation framework

Tags: perl

This is regarding an issue I have been facing for sometime. Though I have found a solution, I really would like to get some opinion about the approach taken.
We have an application which receives messages from a host, does some processing and then pass that message on to an external system. This application is developed in Java and has to run on Linux/Oracle and HP-NonS top Tandem/SQLMX OS/DB combination.
I have developed a test automation framework which is written in Perl.This script traverses directories (specified as an argument to this script)  and executes test cases specified under those directories. Test cases could be organized into directories as per functionality. This approach was taken to ensure that a specific functionality can also checked in addition to entire regression suite.For verification of the test results, script read test case specific input files which has sql queries mentioned in them.
In Linux/Oracle, Perl DBD/DBI interface is used to query Oracle database.
When this automation tool was run in Tandem, I came to know that there was no DBD/DBI interface for SQLMX. When we contacted HP, they informed us that it would be a while before they develop DBD/DBI interfaces for SQLMX DB.
To circumvent this issue, I developed a small Java application which accepts DB connection string, user name, password and various other parameters. This Java app is now responsible for test case verification functionality.
I must say it meets our current needs, but something tells me (do not know what) that approach taken is not a good one, though now I have the flexibility of running this automation with any DB which has a JDBC interface.
Can you please provide feedback on the above approach and suggest a better solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit too broad to comment usefully on except for one part.

If the project is in Java, write the tests in Java.  Writing the tests in a different language adds all sorts of complications.

You have to maintain another programming language and attendant libraries.  They can have different caveats and bugs for the same actions, such as you ran into with a lack of a database driver in a certain environment.

Having the tests done in a different language than the project is developed in drives a wedge between testing and development.  Developers will not feel responsible for participating in the testing process because they don't even know the language.

With the tests written in a different language, they cannot leverage any work which has already been done.  They have to write all over again basic code to access and work with the data and services, doubling the work and doubling the bugs.  If the project code changes APIs or data structures, the test code can easily fall out of sync requiring extra maintenance hassles.

Java already has well developed testing tools to do what you want.  The whole structure of running specific tests vs the whole test suite is built into test suites like jUnit.

So I can underscore the point, I wrote Test::More and I'm recommending you *not* use it here.